# How do I send or save a function and recv or restore a function and execute it in C++?

Tags: c++, function, serialization

Is there any way I can send or save a function as file? I want to do this in C++ on a Windows platform.

I assume that there is some convention between reader and sender or saver

Is it OK if I send like below?
server side:

```
label1:
int func1(int somevar){
    int a = 1;
    return somevar+a;
}
label2:

send(sockfd, label2-label1, sizeof(int), 0) //send a size first
send(sockfd, label1, label2-label1, 0); // send a "function"
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Sending arbitrary code to a remote host is generally considered a Very Bad Idea, primarily because it's a glaring security hole, but also because it's extremely difficult, and definitely impractical, to debug problems. Even if you guaranteed that both machines had the same architecture, you have next to no control over what happens if there's a bug (like, say, if someone put a function call in there). BTW, on several architectures, some C++ builtins (e.g. `operator /` with `double` arguments) are actually function calls.

Comment: I know of one OS that allows this: VxWorks. It has a means where you can upload an object or library file (similar to ELF) to a target, and have the target dynamically link it in. There are big caveats on this, of course, and it's really slow.

Comment: There's stuff like Google NaCl too, although that's transferring more than one function at a time. And the framework on the destination is pretty hefty.

Comment: What you want to do is very, very difficult. It's also very dangerous from a security standpoint. It would be better if you would describe what problem you're trying to solve by serializing (that's what it's called when you transform a piece of data into a string of bytes and back) functions. That problem probably has an easier solution than function serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to do that in C++. Languages which could allow transfer of executable code include Erlang, Ruby, TCL.

Chris

Answer (score 2):

There already exists a mechanism for this in windows for C++. Your functions are "saved" when compiling in a dll. You can then "retrieve" your functions from the dll using `GetProcAddress()`.

Comment: Going by his example, I think that the op wants to send the code from his source via a socket to a remote host so this approach wouldn't really apply.

Comment: He can send dynamic library and load it on the remote host (if processor architectures and/or OS are the same).

Answer (score 2):

With C++ this is definitely not possible.

You could send a precompiled dynamically linked library containing the functions and load and execeute them at the end point.

Answer (score 2):

C++ is a static language - you can't modify the executable you're running and add in new functions.  Languages like Ruby would allow you to do this, but its just not a feature of C++.

You could, if really really needed, possibly put your function in a file, send it over the network, and have your program on the other end compile the file and run it with a popen from your process or something... but that's getting pretty ridiculous by that point.

I'd say redesign so you don't need this.

Answer (score 1):

YOU CAN DO IT!
Just write your own compiler that instead of compiling files, it waits for signals, builds files, and then compiles them. And then possibly runs them.

Basically:

1. send function text
2. receive function text
3. compile with your program the text
4. execute the compiled code
5. ???
6. profit!

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not at all valid. That's basically quite impossible- you would need to use some sort of intermediary language or express the function in assembly or disassemble the resulting binary.